# Android Camera occupies a lot of memory after released

Tags: android, memory-management, android-profiler

I have a very wired situation here:

1. open camera, make some preview
2. stop preview and release everything and finish current activity
3. check the memory leak, and it shows nothing(case i have already fixed them)
4. memory use not recovery just like before camera preview

Here is the profiler
[image]

As the picture shows, every time to open camera, the graphics part is increasingly

When I close camera, this part is decrease a litter, but not return to before camera opend

Along with "open-close" several times, the used graphics memory make an accumulation, even I close the activity, and release everything.

How to I handle it, any help please?